# Apache - proxy using vhosts

Tags: apache2, proxy

I've been trying for a few days now to get this running, but with no luck. I need to accomplish this using apache httpd:

- requests sent to subdomain blog.DOMAIN.TLD sent to port 80 on should return the same as requests on port 2000
- requests sent to the IP of the server directly (without domain names) to port 80 should return data from /var/www (normal webserver)

My last try was this code in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 31.31.79.187
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.noxx2.eu
    <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://31.31.79.187:2368/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://31.31.79.187:2368/
</VirtualHost>
```

This does it job for the subdomain, but for the requests to the IP, it just returns a HTTP 403. 
Any way how to make this running? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

403 is for forbidden access. Is the content there readable by apache (its owner should be www-data)?

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 31.31.79.187
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www>
       stuff in here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```